# mysqli_insert_id() returns 0 on same connection, after insert query

Tags: php, mysql, insert, auto-increment, myisam

Before you ask, i have used the search function of stack overflow and google!

At my code, mysqli_insert_id does always return 0.

In my 'Model'-PHP-Class my save function looks like this:

```
$result = DB::q($sql);

if(!$result)
{
    throw new Exception("Error:".mysqli_error(DB::getDB()));
}
else
{
    if(is_null($this->id))
    {
        $this->id = DB::insert_id();
    }
}

$this->update();
```

My Class DB looks like this:

```
class DB
{
    public static $db = null;

    public static function q($sql)
    {
        self::checkDB();

        if(!isset($sql) OR $sql == null OR $sql == "")
        {
            throw new Exception("\$sql may not be empty");
        }
        else
        {
            $result = mysqli_query(self::$db, $sql);
            if(!$result)
            {
                error_log($sql);
                throw new Exception(mysqli_error(self::$db));
                die();
            }

            return new DBResult($result);
        }
    }

    public static function checkDB()
    {
        if(is_null(self::$db))
        {
            self::$db = mysqli_connect(DB_PORT, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

            if(!self::$db)
            {
                throw new Exception(mysqli_error(self::db));
            }
        }
    }

    public static function insert_id()
    {
        return mysqli_insert_id(self::$db);
    }
}

class DBResult
{
    private $result = null;

    public function __construct($result)
    {
        $this->result = $result;
    }

    public function fetch_assoc()
    {
        return mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->result);
    }

    public function fetch_object()
    {
        return mysqli_fetch_object($this->result);
    }

    public function __get($willget)
    {
        if($willget == "num_rows")
        {
            return mysqli_num_rows($this->result);
        }
        else
        {
            return $this->result;
        }
    }
}
```

When i perform an multi-query directly on the server in the same database, it will work correctly:

```
INSERT INTO users (name, age) VALUES ('personA', 42); SELECT last_insert_id() as k;
```

I also have set the `AUTO_INCREMENT` flag on my `id` column.

Also there seems to be no place in my code between any query, where i will overwrite `$db` in the `DB` class.

Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: Your code seems to work as expected. Something else is wrong. Did you `var_dump(DB::insert_id());` before `if(is_null($this->id))`?

Comment: @Syscall no id didnt. the are not mysqli operations between `DB::q()` and `DB::insert_id()`. I will try to call `DB::insert_id` right after my `DB::q()`.

Comment: Using this code data is inserted in database ? I dont think it is...

Comment: @ShishilPatel Yes, this code is inserted in database.

Comment: Already found the failure. Thanks to @Syscall.

Comment: I don't know why it was, but a decade ago I wrote a comment in my db object "never use mysqli_insert_id because it gives me fits of uncontrolled rage". And had thus gone simply with `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` instead. Which has worked flawlessly for years over millions of auto_increment rows on hundreds of tables. Maybe its better now in PDO or php 7 mysqli ... but stigma and all that... hard to shake.

Comment: Read about the === operator in PHP.  Learn what happens with NULL and 0 and empty string when testing `if($x)`.

Comment: @Rick James. Thanks for your advice. I already know the differences in PHP between NULL, 0, 1, "", "A". Coding with it since a couple of years 8 hours a day. The problem was another. I have expected the Id to be NULL whenever the data has no entry in the database. Instead it was 0. The fault is at another place.